# How to make data loaded from a text file a number in Flash AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have this code

```
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("save.html");


var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(url);


loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);
function loaderComplete(e:Event):void
{
mytext.text=loader.data;
}
```

but if I want to make something like

```
mynumber=Number(loader.data);
mytext=String(mynumber);
```

it gives me NaN, I don't know how to fix it, and also in save.html I only have number 5, nothing else...

Comment: Try to trace loader.data. Why is it an .html file if it doesn't contain html tags?

Comment: Because on my host .txt is not allowed, so I have to use .html, and when I trace it's okay, I need to change to number because I am making highscores, and I have to compare values, and currently I can't do it, if I for example write

    mynum=loader.data;
    if(mynum>bestscore){ do something }

I get can't compare string with number, and if I write

    mynum=Number(loader.data);

and then compare, it gives me false always, and if I try to trace it's NaN, but if I replace loader.data with for example "5" it works just fine

Comment: Try `parseInt` , like: `mynumber=parseInt(loader.data)`

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;

var url = new URLRequest("save.html");
var loader = new URLLoader(url);


loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, doit)
loader.load(url);

function doit(e)
{
  var S:Number = Number(loader.data);
  trace(S);
}
```